# Intel NUC black screen when booting

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have an Intel NUC 5i3RYB

- Intel Core i3 5010U @ 2.1 GHz
- 16 GB RAM (8 GB Crucial + 8 GB Kingston)

When booted, the following things happen:

- POWER LED becomes blue
- HDD LED is blinking for a short time
- nothing else seems to happen
- it only shows a black screen

I have tried

- disconnecting everything (USB, network)
- powering off the hard way
- removing the power supply
- using a different monitor

and powering on again (after each of these options).

I have also tried

- rebooting and going into BIOS with <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> and <kbd>Del</kbd>
- removing the hard disk and scanning for errors with `chkdsk` - no errors were found
- inserting a bootable USB stick with Windows 7 and rebooting
- reading in the [official Intel thread](https://communities.intel.com/thread/39881?start=255&tstart=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, it started to boot normally after I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

May it be useful for others.